# filter datatable by column for results within range ( on button click )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a Datatable with 9 columns in my html document that is created and works perfectly with filtering and searching. 
The table is created with this code:

```html
var productPricingTable = $('#productPriceOpportunitiesTable').DataTable({
      dom: '',       
      "paging": false,
      "info": false
});
```

I have a button and I'm trying to make it so that when the button is pressed, it will filter the datatable so that only rows with a 9th column value between 1.00 - 1.50.

I have my button press detected correctly in the function below, but I'm struggling with writing the code that will filter the datatable correctly.

```html
$("#productTableToggleCheckbox").on('change', function() {
  //productTableToggleCheckbox
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
      //when switch is turned on, filter datatable to only show results where the 9th column's value is between 1.00 to 1.50
      //filter table
      //productPricingTable.column( 8 ).search( $(1.07).text() );
      //productPricingTable.draw()
  }
  else {
      switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
      //switch is turned off
  }
});
```

I'm currently trying with `productPricingTable.column( 8 ).search( $(1.07).text() );` but nothing seems to be happening. Is there some way to modify this line of code so that it filters the table correctly? Something like:

`productPricingTable.column( 8 ).search( col8.value( x >= 1.00 && x <= 1.50) );`

Answer (score 0):

answered with:

```html
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        //if 'Show Only Price Opportunities' button is toggled on:
        if($("#productTableToggleCheckbox").is(':checked')){
          var CPI = parseFloat( data[8] ) || 0; // use data for the age column
          console.log("CPI = ", CPI)
          if(CPI < 0.90 || CPI > 1.10){
            //include row in table if CPI matches criteria
            return true;
          }else{
            //if CPI does not match criteria; 
            return false;
          }

        }else{
          return true;
        }
      }
  );
```